# Mounting directory from windows machine to OracleVMBox for Tensor on Docker

Tags: windows, docker, virtual-machine, tensorflow, mount

I set up a shared folder "tensor" between my Windows machine and the Oracle VM Virtual box called "default". [I run Windows 7, am using Oracle VM Virtual Box Manager, and the Docker Toolbox.]

[image]

Then, I open the Docker Toolbox Quickstart terminal, ssh into "default" VM Box, and can successfully mount the tensor folder into it's directory, like so:

[image]

I created "hello_world.txt" on my local computer and the file displayed in the VM.

My issue is that I cannot seem to figure out how to have this directory be used when I run the tensorflow image in a container within the default box (also, i am new to this, so please correct me if my terminology here is wrong).

I exit out of the "default" box, and back to my Docker Client terminal. I tried running the following variations of commands (sourced from multiple websites):

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 -v /mnt/tensor:/tensor --name tf gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow
```

This lets me access the Jupyter notebook when i got to http://DEFAULT_IP:8888, but I do not see the "tensor" folder that I expect to see. Instead, the directory is just empty.

However, i assumed in the command above that -v DIRECTORY_VM:DIRECTORY_CONTAINER, so that the first address that I give it is the directory within my default VM, which is to map to a directory inside the container running with the tensor image.

Second trial is that I tried this:

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 -v //c/Users/rebeccak.REBECCAPC/tensor:/tensor --name tf gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow
```

In this case, I provided the path to the "tensor" folder on my local machine instead of the VM Box.

Still no success. Could someone tell me how to do this correctly? Thank you.

Also, when I run "docker inspect CONTAINER_NAME" for one of my attempts, I got this for mounts:

[image]

So the "source" folder does not look like the path I specified. Where is this address? Is it on my "default" vm or is it on my daemon client/linux machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did declare a shared folder on VirtualBox, but you still need to properly mount it in your VM.

In your ssh session:

```
sudo touch /mnt/sda1/var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh
```

> Add to that file:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/tensorflow
mount -t vboxsf -o defaults,uid=`id -u docker`,gid=`id -g docker` tensorflow /mnt/tensorflow
```

Then restart your docker-machine (stop, start)

A `-v /mnt/tensor:/tensor` should now work.

Check of course that your source folder does exist: that was [OP RebeccaK375](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2707197/rebeccak375)'s [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640076/mounting-directory-from-windows-machine-to-oraclevmbox-for-tensor-on-docker/38654287#comment64876331_38654287):

> My issue was actually that there was not a "`tensor`" folder to mount,

Comment: Thank you for your comment! My issue was actually that there was not a "tensor" folder to mount, which was a silly error on my part, but I thought your answer would help most who would find my question. Many thanks!

Comment: @RebeccaK375 OK. I have included your issue in the answer for more visibility.